# How to get string from a text til first space with a recursive function?

Tags: string, haskell, recursion

In my homework, my task is to write a recursive function which returns the first word of a text and `""` if the first character is a space.

Here is my function:

```
takeWord :: [Char] -> [Char]
takeWord [] = []
takeword (x:xs) 
    | x == ' ' = []
    | otherwise = x : takeword xs
```

It should work like this:

```
takeWord " one"    = ""
takeWord "one two" = "one"
takeWord ""        = ""    --returns with "Non-exhaustive patterns in function takeword"
takeWord "one"     = "one" --and this too
```

But at the cases where is no space, it returns with this error message:

> Non-exhaustive patterns in function takeword

What would be the correct code?

Comment: Your second function is `takeword` with a lowercase, it should be `takeWord`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You defined two functions here: `takeWord`, with an uppercase `W`, and `takeword` with a lowercase `w`. The former one only works with empty lists, the latter one only works with non-empty lists.

You thus should pick one of the two names, like:

```
takeWord :: [Char] -> [Char]
takeWord [] = []
takeWord (x:xs) 
    | x == ' ' = []
    | otherwise = x : takeWord xs
```

we can make it a bit more elegant by matching with a space in the pattern, and not in the guard:

```
takeWord :: [Char] -> [Char]
takeWord [] = []
takeWord (' ':_) = ""
takeWord (x:xs) = x : takeWord xs
```

Note that you can make use of [**`takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) here:

```
takeWord :: [Char] -> [Char]
takeWord = takeWhile (' ' /=)
```